# Can I make 3-D rotating text sphere only with the help of html , css and js only not the react js or any library

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to make a 3d rotating text sphere with the help of html,  css and js only , I don't want to include any libraries because I am a beginner to js.

Pure code of html, css and js

Comment: No Javascript: [Text on a 3D circular path](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/full/WNEzyEw)